# Why can't i redefine the Body Variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to redefine an JavaScript variable in an `.catch`, but that does not work.

index.js:

```js
const Restra = async function(username) {
    let status;

    const Fetch = require("node-fetch"),
        Url = "https://instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1"

        let Body = await Fetch(Url).then((res) => {
            status = res.status
            return res.json()
        })
        .catch((e) =>  {
            if(status === 404) return console.error("Status Code response was 404. Try an other Account Username")
            Body = null
        })

    return console.log(Body)
}

Restra("whaterverusernamethathopefullynotexists")
```

Console Output:

C:\Users\Dimitri\Restra>node .
Status Code response was 404. Try an other Account Username
undefined

Answer (score 2):

What `.catch` does is, if the Promise it's being called on rejects, the `catch` turns it into a Promise that *resolves* to the value returned in the `catch`. Since your `catch` isn't returning anything, although you reassign `Body` to `null`, once the `.catch` and the whole Promise chain finishes, the `undefined` is assigned to `Body`.

Return `null` inside the `catch` instead:

```js
const Restra = async function(username) {
  const Url = "https://instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1"
  const Body = await fetch(Url).then((res) => {
      status = res.status
      if (status === 404) {
        console.error("Status Code response was 404. Try an other Account Username");
        // Go to the catch:
      }
      return res.json()
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return null;
    })

  return console.log(Body)
}

Restra("whaterverusernamethathopefullynotexists")
```

Comment: is there an way to return nothing?

Comment: Sure, just omit `return` statements, and nothing will be returned

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Remove the `return` line

Answer (score 1):

A far as I understand you want to overwrite body with `null` but you are returning the `console.log()` before overwriting `Body` so it never reaches that line.